# KB5005043 affected decrypting web.config?

Tags: iis

On Friday the 13th this KB 5005043 got installed on Windows 2016 server.  Our application which reads an encrypted connectionstrings.config through a web.config file suddenly started complaining.

```
Message : Failed to decrypt using provider 'RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'. Error message from the provider: The data to be decrypted exceeds the maximum for this modulus of 128 bytes.
```

The web.config / connectionstrings.config hasn't changed since 8/3 (and still hasn't), the application was running since then without an issue until the morning of 8/13 when the 'failed to decrypt' errors started appearing.  The only connection we see is that this Windows KB got applied on the same day.  The only known issue that the KB mentions is something about Windows 2008 SP2 (who runs this??)

Has anyone seen a similar issue?

Comment: Contact Microsoft support via http://support.microsoft.com for assistance on hotfix related issues.

Answer (score 0):

Open aspnet_regiis.exe tool and execute as Administrator, try to use this command `aspnet_regiis -pa`.

More information you can refer to this link: [Encrypting and Decrypting Configuration Sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/zhhddkxy(v=vs.100)).